# In Django load a CSS file depending on a variable name and only if it exists

Tags: django, django-templates

In Django I wish to load a CSS file only if it exists. The name should be created by a variable name.

Something like this kind of works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/core/css/{{ site.id }}.css" />
```

But the problem is of curse, that it always tries to laod the file, wether it exists or not. Also I would like to use the "static" template tag, but this does not work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "core/css/{{ site.id }}.css" %}" />
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Simple use the if statement.

```
{% if site.id %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "core/css/"+{{ site.id}}+".css" %}" />
{% endif %}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Ok, I did not know that I can just do "if site.id", but that does not test if the file is there. In my setup every "site" has an id, but not every id has some css file.

Comment: Embedding {{ site.id }}  (double curly braces) inside a template tag like that won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '' %}core/css/{{ site.id }}.css"/>
```

And for checking if file exits or not you can write custom template tag

> app/templatetags/static_check.py

```
from django import template
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles import finders
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def is_static_file_exists(site_id):
    abs_path = finders.find('core/css/%s.css' % (site_id))
    return staticfiles_storage.exists(abs_path)
```

> template.html

```
  {% load static static_check %}

  {% if site.id|is_static_file_exists %}
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '' %}core/css/{{ site.id }}.css"/>
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it does only answer the second, less important part of the question. The question (How to load the file only if it exists?) remains.

Comment: I guess that almost works, but it gets me this error:

ERROR django.security.SuspiciousFileOperation get_response [204]: The joined path (/home/leonhard/mega/ceres/ceres/git/ceres/assets/core/css/1.css) is located outside of the base path component (/home/leonhard/mega/ceres/ceres/git/ceres/static)
[30/Apr/2018 16:51:51] "GET /de/ HTTP/1.1" 400 257385

Comment: @mogoh What is the location of your static files?

Comment: I have now tested if not None and suggested it as an edit.